# Why won't FWDN see my cheap Chinese tablet?

Tags: tablet

I have a tablet here that appears to be a NuPad / HAIPAD M701.

[image: My Tablet]

I have downloaded a .RAR with FWDN. When I run FWDN the "Area Map" always shows "Unknown".

I have tried this on both a Windows 7 x64 and a Windows XP x32 machine.

I have run the VTC driver installer on XP (it doesn't work on x64).

What does it mean when Area Map says Unknown, and how do I fix it?

[image: FWDN is blank]

Comment: Nice iPad-like exterior :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was needing in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eQ7Z6_v_Fc

I was holding down the wrong side of the rocker switch when booting, ending up in "recovery" mode.